# linux : Setting process core affinity in assembly language(NASM)

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, affinity, cpu-cores

I have question I was wondering if I could set processor core affinity of a linux process using assembly program. I am using nasm for assembling. There is an interrupt for creating a process but I don't how to set core affinity.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) system call.

The system call number is found in the macro `__NR_sched_setaffinity`.

Answer (score 1):

For performance experiments, `taskset -c 1 ./a.out`  or `taskset -c 1 perf stat ./a.out` are what I normally use to avoid CPU migrations.  Or with a set of CPUs for code that starts multiple threads, or different `taskset` commands to start two separate processes pinned to different physical cores, or to logical cores which share the same physical core to see how they compete with each other.

I also specify a bunch of events including the default plus some others that are useful on Intel Skylake:

```
taskset -c 1 perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,idq.mite_uops
```

---

This avoids the need to write asm that makes a `sched_setaffinity` system call, but you can certainly do that.  `int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize, unsigned long *mask);` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html))

- `pid = 0` means this thread.
- The `cpusetsize` is in bytes, not bits.  The minimum is `sizeof(unsigned long)` = 8 (on x86-64).

  On Linux kernels before 2.6.9, it was an error (`EINVAL`) to call with a size smaller than the kernel's internal data structure, but it's not anymore.  So I assume the kernel just zero-extends a 1-chunk (8-byte) mask if you're on a system with more than 64 CPUs.
  `sched_getaffinity` does still return `EINVAL` for sizes smaller than the kernel's internal mask.
- `mask` is a pointer to a bit-array.

> C library/kernel differences  ([in the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html#NOTES))
>
> This manual page describes the glibc interface for the CPU
> affinity calls.  The actual system call interface is slightly
> different, with the mask being typed as `unsigned long *`,
> reflecting the fact that **the underlying implementation of CPU
> sets is a simple bit mask**.
>
> On success, the raw sched_getaffinity() system call returns the
> number of bytes placed copied into the mask buffer; this will be
> the minimum of cpusetsize and the size (in bytes) of the
> cpumask_t data type that is used internally by the kernel to
> represent the CPU set bit mask.

Glibc's `cpu_set_t` with a fixed `sizeof(T) = 128` (1024 bits) is an invention of the library, as the glibc man page documents.

---

`strace taskset -c 1  some-command` shows us how it uses them:

```
...
sched_getaffinity(0, 256, [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]) = 8
sched_setaffinity(0, 8, [1])            = 0
...
```

My system is an i7-6700k Skylake, 4c8t, so internally the kernel only needs one `unsigned long` chunk of bits, thus `sched_getaffinity` returns 8 (bytes), and `taskset` uses that size for the new mask.  (For compat with Linux 2.6.8 and earlier I assume, to discover the minimum size of mask to use).

You could  instead use the highest specified CPU number to calculate a mask size like `(max+63)/64 * 8`, where 64 is number of bits in an `unsigned long` and `8` is its size in bytes.  So round up to the number of `unsigned long` chunks to include the one containing the highest bit-position we need to set.  (If turning a list of integers into a bitmask, you'd find the max, then loop through them setting the appropriate bit.  Perhaps with `bts` for small code size but low performance.)

The `unsigned long *mask` data structure is a bitmap aka bit-array so the simplistic slow way to set bits in it is with `bts dword [rdx], 127` to set the bit corresponding to core #127, for example.  Obviously instructions like `or`, `and`, and `xor` work, too.

For a large mask you can zero 256 bits with `vpxor xmm0, xmm0` / `vmovups [rdx], ymm0` and then set one or a couple bits in it.

**But if you just want to pin to a low-numbered core (in the low 31 bits), you can use a sign-extended 32-bit immediate to store a 64-bit value to memory and pass the kernel a pointer to that.**  For example `mov qword [rdx], 0b1010_1111_0000` to allow running on cores 4-7, and 9 and 11, but not any others.

Other ways to write that constant in NASM include `(1<<11) | (1<<9) | 0xf0`

#### Working example: pins itself to CPU 2 and spins for a couple seconds

```
__NR_sched_setaffinity equ 203         ; TODO, generate this from text processing on asm/unistd_64.h

global _start
_start:

    xor   edi, edi         ; pid = 0  = this thread
    mov   esi, 8           ; cpusetsize = sizeof(unsigned long) = qword
    push  0b0000_0100      ; 1<<2   = CPU #2.   8-bit or 32-bit sign-extended constant
    mov   rdx, rsp
; or lea rdx, [rsp-8] ; mov qword [rdx], 0x0f0f0f0f   to use the red zone instead of moving RSP
    mov   eax, __NR_sched_setaffinity
    syscall                ; sched_setaffinity(0, 8, mask)

    mov ecx, 10000000
.loop:
    times 4 pause      ; waste as little power as possible while occupying a CPU
    dec  ecx
    jnz .loop


   mov eax, 231      ; __NR_exit_group
;  xor edi, edi      ; still zero from earlier
   syscall           ; exit_group(0)   stops all threads even if there are more than one.
    ; __NR_exit = 60  would only exit the current thread.  Still ending the process if it's the last thread.
```

Assemble + link with

```
nasm -f elf64 pin.asm &&
ld -o pin  pin.o
```

If you start it with `taskset -c 2 perf stat ./pin`, CPU-migrations will be `0`.  Otherwise it'll be `1` if you start it pinned to a different core.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its pretty late and I have lost touch with the nasm so wont be able to verify the answer.

Comment: @raghu777: That's fine, I assumed you'd already figured out whatever problem you had 10 years ago.  I wrote this for any future readers that find this via search.  Cool that you're still around on Stack Overflow to see it at all. :)